# Date in Edit field PHP

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
   else{
  $this->addDataControl('Zeit', 'gesch_aufwand', array(DEFAULTVALUE=>TRUE, 'caption'=>'Anf. Geschätzter Aufwand', 'data_type'=>'integer', 'max_hour'=>87600),REQUIRED);
  $this->addDataControl('Datum', 'start', array('caption'=>'Start'));
  $this->addDataControl('Datum', 'due', array('caption'=>'Ende', DEFAULTVALUE=>TRUE), REQUIRED);
}
```

Currently, the 3 (1 for day, 1 for Month..)fields are Emty. But I want them bot tho show the current Date DDMMYYYY. How do i realize this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried `'default' => date('Y-m-d')` in the array and it worked